# SSRS hiding a row group if there are no detail rows

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

Can someone please help me write a custom code that will check if the details of the row group = nothing? I'd like to use this as a show/hide expression such that table 0 will not display if there are no records within the group.

[image]

I can't seem to use aggregations for the row group details at the row group level.

Edit:
example 1 with a detail row
[image]

example 2 with without a detail row but the group header still displays. I'd like to hide this group completely:
[image]

Comment: If there is not data in the group it will not show anyway. This probably means that you have data in that group. Show an exmaple of you dataset results and your report design. Also show an example of how the group can be "empty". Once you supply this, I'm sure one of us will be able to help.

Comment: @AlanSchofield just added. i'm not sure why the group without details still shows and thought i needed to write an expression...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like you want to hide a table, not just a group within a table.

If this is not correct , please post your full report design.

You should be able to just count the rows in the dataset that the table is bound to.
So if your table is bound to `DataSet`` the 'Hidden' property would just be

```
=COUNTROWS("DataSet1") = 0
```

`"DataSet1"` is the name of the dataset, it is case sensitive and must be enclosed in double quotes.

The table will be hidden but the space it consumes will not be used, in other words, you will have a blank space where the table should be.

Alternatively, you can set the `NoRowsMessage` property to simple text message or an expression which will be displayed instead of just hiding the table.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value), Parameters!ShowMissingGroup.Value,False) for the row group expression visibility then using a parameter to hide/show it.